# Typescript: Create Object from another Type but in a "Left Outer Join" Fashion

Tags: typescript, types, key

We are trying to create an object based on another which includes all records from the `Man` Type, and the matched fields from the `Person` Type. So an example:

```
interface Person{
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

interface Man{
  name: string;
  height: number;
}

const jane = {
  name: 'Jane',
  age: 26
} as Person;
```

So what we want to end up with is something like `const mark = {...jane, height: 160} as Man;` and so mark should contain `{name: 'Jane', height: 160}` (i know the name is odd but it's just an example)

Comment: Hello jcalz, referencing a line in the other question: "In a general way, how can you make the 'reduced' variable to only contain the properties declared in the 'MyInterface' interface." To me (in sql terms) this is asking for the Inner Join, where my question is asking for a Left (or Right) Outer Join.

Comment: You want `mark` to only contain the properties declared in the `Man` interface, right?  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGVqvm)?  If so, this is a duplicate.  If not, please [edit] the question to clearly distinguish what you're asking for from that.  (btw, I know what inner/left/right joins are in sql, but I'm not catching how you're using them in reference to these types.  If you could rephrase in terms of TS props and not in terms of sql that would be great)

Comment: I think in the end you are right @jcalz, this seems like a duplicate. We were hoping for a more dynamic way to do what Vitaliy did in the other question, without the need to hard-code the fields to reduce. Alas this does not seem possible without writing our own function or using a library.

Comment: @jcalz hopefully didnt speak too soon, but tried what Vitaliy did but we end up NOT getting back the `height` key in our new Object. We get an error `Property 'height' does not exist on type...`

Comment: I can only speak to [my version](https://tsplay.dev/WGVqvm) which works as far as I can tell.  If I'm missing something then you could edit the question to explain, although at this point it's already closed as a duplicate which I might or might not be allowed to undo

Comment: @jcalz You are still correct in that this is a duplicate, your code does accomplish what we need. This should stay closed. I guess we were "hoping" for a simpler solution ha.. Yours is hard to wrap my head around how it works, but no fault to you. Here is something we went with: https://tsplay.dev/N91kjN